# F# and resulting type would be infinite error

Tags: .net, f#

I have the following recursive function :

```
let rec ComputePath v items =
                match v with
                | x when x <> source -> ComputePath edgeTo.[x] x::items
                | s when s = source -> s::items
                | _ -> items
            ComputePath v [] |> Some
```

In the third line wherein I am calling the recursive function, I am getting the following error : Type mismatch. Resulting type would be infinite when unifying a' and a list'.

If I change the method parameters by converting them into tuple, then the error goes away.

```
let rec ComputePath (v, items) =
                match v with
                | x when x <> source -> ComputePath (edgeTo.[x], x::items)
                | s when s = source -> s::items
                | _ -> items
            ComputePath (v, []) |> Some
```

edgeTo is an integer array. What change do I need to do in the original function definition to make it work?

Comment: It's just a guess because obvious we cannot try but just get some `(...)` around `x::items` - remember: function application has the highest predecence: `| x when x <> source -> ComputePath edgeTo.[x] (x::items)`

Comment: see: without it you will have this `(ComputePath edgeTo.[x] x) :: items` and  the error message makes a lot of sense

Comment: in the tuple case you obviously included the parents ;)

Comment: Thanks. Adding parenthesis around x::items i.e. (x::items) solved the problem.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer if you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to put some `(...)` around `x::items`

**remember**: function application has the highest predecence:

```
match v with
| x when x <> source -> ComputePath edgeTo.[x] (x::items)
....
```

### reason

without it you will end up having this:

```
(ComputePath edgeTo.[x] x) :: items
```

and the error message makes a lot of sense